# Does one have to wait six hour after eating a sharp object cut with a meat knife?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food

The [Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.96.1?lang=bi&with=Ba%27er%20Hetev&lang2=en) says that when one cuts a sharp food with a knife, it makes the flavor in the knife "BeEin" - as if it were visible (and not just a "taste").

Is that only for the laws of "Nat Bar Nat" or also for the laws of waiting six hours?

Comment: There are two reasons to wait 6 hours (food between the teeth or digestion time) neither apply to the sharp food that has been cut with a the meat knife, and therefore there is no need to wait for 6 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Darkei Teshuvah YD 89:42, (paragraph beginning ועיין)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40536&st=&pgnum=281) discusses this question in depth, and quotes various sources in both directions.  See also [here](http://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A3-%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%9C-%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%95/), final paragraph, which seems to understand the conclusion of the Darkei Teshuva to be that it is permitted.  This is certainly the Minhag (and the standard Pesak), as can be seen from [here](http://din.org.il/2012/03/29/%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%9C-%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%9A-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99/) (second comment) and [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/15076).